# Why is it asking me to surround BufferReader object with try catch when I already have that?

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader

I am writing a program in which I am taking input from user using BufferedReader object and then catching the IOException thrown by BufferedReader object in catch block but still when I am closing the resources in finally block then why is it saying to surround with try/catch or declare IOException

### Here is the program

```
public class BufferedReader3 {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStreamReader  r=null;
        BufferedReader br=null;
        String name="";    



        

        try 
        {
            
            r =new InputStreamReader(System.in);    
            br =new BufferedReader(r); 
            while(!name.equals("stop"))
            {    

                System.out.println("Enter data: ");   
                name=br.readLine();
            } 



            System.out.println("data is: "+name);    


        }              
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally
        {

            br.close();    
            r.close();    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `try-catch` with resources will solve this problem. I think the problem has something to do with dereferencing a potential null pointer. Just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

The `close` method can throw an `IOException` for the following reason [(source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close--):

> If an I/O error occurs

Which is why the `IOException` which the `close` method might throw also needs to be caught, since it's in the `finally` block it's not within your already existing `try catch` block:

```
finally {
    try {
        br.close();
        r.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```